# How do I populate database values into an existing object model?

Tags: java, database, apache-commons, apache-commons-dbutils

I have a model instance already, it's a basic POJO, how can I populate it (by issuing a `SELECT`) with the values using [dbutils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) by calling the setters which are named to match the table column names?

So [BasicRowProcessor](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/index.html) should match, I just don't find the appropiate class/method to call with the object as parameter.

There is only one instance I want to set, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Some source code would help.

There are lots of libraries that perform ORM. See [source forge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=&fq%5B%5D=trove:45&fq%5B%5D=trove:809&fq%5B%5D=trove:198) for some ORM projects. One of them is [sormula](http://www.sormula.org) which I created. For the simplest use of it, see [POJO zero-config example](http://www.sormula.org/zero-config/).

Comment: I was looking for something like (to the example you've linked) `inventoryTable.selectInto(partNumber, inventory);` - inventory being the already existing POJO, I want to just populate it with data.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is

```
YourObject result = new BasicRowProcessor().toBean(yourResultSet,YourObject.class);
```

It will create the instance though. This API is not designed to allow you to modify an already existing object.

If you really need to update the existing object you might implement a `YourObject.copy(YourObject obj)` method and call it with the result from `BasicRowProcessor.toBean` but it looks quite ugly.

An other (also ugly) solution would be to implement the `BeanProcessor` class, implement the `BeanProcessor.newInstance(Class)` method to return your object, then pass your implementation instance to the `BasicRowProcessor` instance.

Comment: Are there any other alternative libraries which DO allow me to do this?